# Walking on uneven terrain, feet leg hip rotation

Tags: c#, xna

I would like to know the algorithm for detecting uneven terrain and rotating the feet to match the plane of the land as well as hips and legs. We are writing a game where this will be very key.

Answer (score 3):

The solution you're looking for is [inverse kinematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics#Robotics_and_3D_Animation).

Comment: The "kinematic chain" in this example would be the bones and joints of the character.